# Overwrite last line on terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, escaping

My bash-script looks as following:

```
echo "Description:"
while [ $finishInput -eq 0 ]; do
  read tmp
  desc="$desc"$'\n'"$tmp"
  if [ -z "$tmp" ]; then
    finishInput="1"
  fi
done
echo -n "Maintainer:"
read maintainer
```

It reads to the desc var until a empty line is passed. After that, i want to read in other stuff.

When executing my current script it looks like this:

```
Description:
Line 1
Line 2

Maintainer:
```

I would like to overwrite the last empty line with the "Maintainer:".

I searched for a solution but only found suggestions which were like

```
echo -n "Old line"
echo -e "\r new line"
```

which stays on the line and overwrites it. This is not possible in my case.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

In your example you delete the text at the same line. When you want to return to the previous line use `\e[1A`, and to clear that line, use `\e[K`:

```
echo 'Old line'
echo -e '\e[1A\e[Knew line'
```

When you want to go `N` lines up, use `\e[<N>A`

Comment: You also stay on the same line using -n. This is not possible in my case as written above.

Comment: Better to have the `\r` before the `\e[0K`, otherwise you'll wipe to the right and then move left, possibly leaving junk between where you were and are. Though since it should be a blank line, neither are strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Where can you find such special characters?

Comment: just google `terminal ansi sequences`. One of results: http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

Comment: @Zulakis: See `man 5 terminfo` and use `tput` instead of hard-coded sequences. `tput cuu1` goes up one line, `tput cuu 4` goes up 4 lines, `tput el` clears to end of line. You can save these in variables and reduce the overhead of repeatedly calling `tput`: `ceol=$(tput el)` and later `echo "foo\r${ceol}A"`

Comment: Just wondering - is there support for doing something like that but from within a compiled program? i.e. some C program, for example.

Comment: @sherrellbc if you're still wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3219471/2954547

Comment: @IgorChubin The link you posted is incredibly helpful. However, it only mentions `\e[K`, `\e[1K`, and `\e[2K`. I'm assuming `\e[0K` is the same as `\e[K`? If so, why not use `\e[2K` instead of `\r\e[0K`?

Comment: @Kevin Your opinion on the above would be nice too. Just not sure if there's any edge-case/caveats/weird-quirks that would make one more reliable than the other.

Answer (score 82):

Found a great [guide on escape sequences](https://shiroyasha.svbtle.com/escape-sequences-a-quick-guide-1) and wanted to expand on some of the discussions here.

When you write out to a terminal, you move an invisible cursor around, much like you do when you write in any text editor. When using `echo`, it will automatically end the output with a new line character which moves the cursor to the next line.

```
$ echo "Hello" && echo " World"
Hello
 World
```

You can use `-n` to prevent the new line and if you echo again after this, it will append it to the end of that line

```
$ echo -n "Hello" && echo " World"
Hello World
```

The cursor remains where it was so, on it's own, we can't use `-n` to overwrite the previous line, we need to move the cursor to the left. To do that we need to give it an escape sequence, which we let `echo` know we're going to use with `-e` and then move the cursor by providing a return carriage `\r` which puts the cursor at the beginning of the line.

```
$ echo -n "Hello" && echo -e "\rWorld"
World
```

That may look like it worked, but see what happens with

```
$ echo -n "A longer sentence" && echo -e "\rShort sentence"
Short sentencence
```

See the extra characters? Simply writing over the line only changes the characters where we wrote them.

To fix this, the accepted answer above uses the escape character `\e[0K` to erase everything after the cursor, after the cursor has moved left. i.e. `\r` move to beginning `\e[0K` erase to end.

```
$ echo -n "A longer sentence" && echo -e "\r\e[0KShort sentence"
Short sentence
```

**Important** `\e` to begin escape sequences works in `zsh` but not in `sh` and not necessarily in `bash`, however `\033` works in all of them. If you want your script to work anywhere, you should preference `\033`

```
$ echo -n "A longer sentence" && echo -e "\r\033[0KShort sentence"
Short sentence
```

But escape characters can provide even more utility. For example `\033[1A` moves the cursor to the previous line so we don't need the `-n` on the previous echo:

```
$ echo "A longer sentence" && echo -e "\r\033[1A\033[0KShort sentence"
Short sentence
```

`\r` move to the beginning `\033[1A` move up `\033[0K` erase to the end

Finally, this is all a bit messy in my book, so you can turn this into a function:

```
overwrite() { echo -e "\r\033[1A\033[0K$@"; }
```

Using `$@` just puts all the parameters of the function into the string

```
$ echo Longer sentence && overwrite Short sentence
Short sentence
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to the guide. It is greatly helpful.

Answer (score 26):

I built a function from [Dennis Williamsons Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283625/bash-overwrite-last-terminal-line#comment14841764_11283860):

```
function clearLastLine() {
        tput cuu 1 && tput el
}
```

Thanks to Dennis Williamson

Comment: Can you explain what those `tput` do?

Comment: @Zim "cuu #" is short for "cursor up # lines" and "el" -> "Clear to end of line", see: [gnu.org - tput](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html)

Comment: Best solution IMO (as it prevent keeping the end of the last line if new one is shorter).

Answer (score 17):

If you echo without the newline character `echo -n "Something"`, you can use `\r` with your next echo to move the '*cursor*' to the beginning of the line `echo -e "\\rOverwrite something"`.

[image: bash overwrite terminal line]

```
#!/bin/bash

CHECK_MARK="\033[0;32m\xE2\x9C\x94\033[0m"

echo -e "\n\e[4mDoing Things\e[0m"
echo -n "doing thing 1..."
sleep 1
echo -e "\\r${CHECK_MARK} thing 1 done"
```

Just be aware that if your new string is shorter that your old string, the tail of your old string will still be visible. Note the `done..` in the gif above.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run a script in a loop and not blow up your scrollback, you can use the following pattern:

```
while sleep 10s; do 
  echo -n $(script)
  echo -n -e "\e[0K\r"
done
```

Just replace the `script` command with your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Description:"
while test -z $finishInput; do
 read -s tmp
 desc="$desc"$'\n'"$tmp"
 if [ -z "$tmp" ]; then
 finishInput=1
 else
    echo $tmp
 fi
 #echo "fi="$finishInput;
done
echo -n "Maintainer:"
read maintainer
```

This solution avoids the empty line, but input is not echoed before the lines are complete.

Hint: My version of bash did not accept "[ $finishInput -eq 0 ]".

Comment: I would rather not like this, because users won't see their input until they enter a newline.

Comment: Since you say "Hint" I presume you know why that line was not "accepted". In case you or someone else may not know, it's because the variable is empty and unquoted. You should use `[ "$finishInput" -eq 0 ]` or better: `[[ $finishInput -eq 0 ]]`.

Comment: [ "$finishInput" -eq 0 ] causes error message "integer expression expected" with my bash. My bash version is 4.2-2ubuntu2.