# How to overwrite the current console line after gets in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, carriage-return, gets

I have this piece of code:

```
def wait_for_input regex
  print "> ".red
  someInput = gets
  
  while (regex =~ someInput).is_a? NilClass do
    print "\r> ".red
    someInput = gets
    
    STDOUT.flush
  end
  
  someInput
end
```

The carriage return is supposed to overwrite the current line in console, but **instead doesn't and the ">" goes in new line.**

*I tried removing the color from the string* (library `colorize`) and writing `$stdout.flush` or `STDOUT.flush` [following this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963717/how-to-overwrite-a-printed-line-in-the-shell-with-ruby) **with no luck**.

Then I realized that *it works if I remove the* `gets` *instruction*.

How to overwrite the current line after `gets`?

Comment: `.is_a? NilClass` - why? There's only one instance of `NilClass` and that's `nil`. If you want to be explicit - you don't have to be - use `== nil` or `.nil?`.

Comment: @cremno because according to the documentation (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html) for 2.2.0, the `=~` operator returns nil... So using `.nil?` would check it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwriting current line (printing `"\r"`) works just fine with `gets`. The thing is, `gets` reads a line until (and including) a linebreak. So it is you, pressing `ENTER`, who moves cursor to a next line. And then this next, already empty, line is rewinded by `\r`.

<s>Moving to a previous line is not possible in the regular mode.</s> (see comments) You need to use a lower-level terminal window access. `curses` is a popular library. Ruby has bindings for it. I suggest you start with this blog post (and follow-ups to it): http://graysoftinc.com/terminal-tricks/random-access-terminal

Comment: Ok, I got it, I need to move up a line.

Comment: Thanks, Sergio. Does this work for both Windows and Linux terminals?

Comment: on a posix terminal it should work. windows - I think not. It's not a real terminal, you know :)

Comment: ANSI escape sequences are even supported on Windows (by any modern CRuby version at least): `print "\e[A\e[2K"` (moves cursor one line up and clears the line). Of course, using `curses` or `highline` (a more high level library) might be preferable.

Comment: @cremno Hm, didn't know about this escape code. Want to post an answer? :)

Comment: @cremno I'll give a look to `curses` and `highline`

Comment: @cremno `print "\e[A\e[2K"` doesn't work... I tried it, and Ubuntu's console just shows `[A[2K> `

Comment: @cremno I faced up the problem, `print` is not the right function. `$stdout.write` does the trick.

Comment: @Nomid: That's weird but good to hear that you've found a solution. `colorize` also uses them (see `p "> ".red`) but maybe your shell differentiates between color and cursor ones. I'd recommend looking at [`highline`](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'll check them. I don't know why `print` doesn't work.